# Nginx try_files return default error when the file is exists

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

When the app is down, Nginx returns default error page, not the page I specified.
What am I doing wrong with sending the `maintenance.html`?

I got this Nginx config for the server:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate     /root/certs/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /root/certs/cert.key;

        server_name example.com;
        
        error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 @maintenance;
        
        location / {    
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location @maintenance {
                root /var/html;
                try_files /maintenance.html =404;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. Moved `maintenance.html` from `/var/html` to `/usr/share/nginx/html` and it worked (probably was a permission error)